# Plotting all values except NaN leaving gaps

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I want to create a time series of an array which has several NaN values. Plotting this produces a weird plot with values that go up to infinity and distort the graph.

The array to be plotted is `myarray`, and I have tried using the command `myarray_masked = np.ma.array(myarray, mask=np.isnan(myarray))`, but plotting this array produces the same weird figure.

This is the code I am using:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

myarray_masked = np.ma.array(myarray, mask=np.isnan(myarray))
x=np.arange(len(myarray_masked))
plt.plot(x, myarray_masked, linewidth=0.1, color=col)
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19661198/matplotlib-plot-numpy-arrays-with-none-as-values.  It suggests using numpy.nan as the value, and that will cause gaps to appear.

Comment: @jszakmeister The values are indeed `numpy.nan`'s

Comment: I tried the example in the solution pointed out, and it does indeed skip the points.  I tried creating an array with numpy.nan for your example too, and it does appear to leave gaps as well (if you skip the masking and define a color).

Comment: @jszakmeister yes, it works like that, thank you very much